# How to export C++ object in R back to C++?

Tags: r, rcpp

In the example below, I have no difficulty exporting some normal c++ method into R using `RCPP_MODULE` except the method `clone` that makes the compilation failed.

```
struct C
{
    void clone(C* other)
    {
         *this = *other;
    }
};

#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

RCPP_MODULE(mod){
    class_<C>("C")
        .method("clone", &C::clone)
        ;
};
```

How to export the `clone` method so I can reference to other C++ class that is created in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works with the development version of Rcpp. See [this article](http://romainfrancois.blog.free.fr/index.php?post/2012/10/25/Rcpp-modules-more-flexible) on my blog.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(C)

struct C
{
    void clone(const C& other)
    {
         *this = other;
    }
};

RCPP_MODULE(play){
    class_<C>("C")
        .method("clone", &C::clone)
        ;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an Rcpp method called clone, so try renaming yours.

Comment: No, renaming clone to clone2 doesn't work. The problem is RCPP_MODULE can't recognize parameter `C*`.

Comment: Well, if everything else fails you could **read the Rcpp Modules documentation** and learn how you are supposed to use this.